# Response Time Out on IIS7, cannot extend to more than 30 sec (default)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, http, iis-7, session-state

I have a website which is using .net 3.5, IIS7 and SQL Server 2008.

On a webpage, click on a `report download button`, it loads data from SQL Server and Stream to user as an excel file.

It works fine except when the execution time and Loading time (from SQL Server) is over 30sec, then the web page time out.

I tried to change the web.config (may be wrong), but it doesn't help.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

Can I solve this issue by configuring just IIS7? or SQL Server/Session State DB/Browser has the timeout restriction as well?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQLCommand object then there is a property "CommandTimeout" which you can set and your processing should not fail.

Comment: Yes it is 30 sec, if it answered your question please check mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks for ur anwser. Is there any risk or security issue or any other drawback by extending the SQLCommand time out?

Comment: No risk at all only your connection will be active & open to receive response from Database for specified no. of seconds.

Comment: Well, one risk of sorts would be that someone could try a denial-of-service against you, if you have something that's publicly accessible that requires a huge amount of processing power. I'm guessing whatever you're doing occupies your database pretty thoroughly while it's running, so that could be a vector for someone attacking your site. Admittedly, if you were already near 30 seconds, upping the timeout only means that your resource-heavy task is just getting even heavier, so it's not that upping the timeout introduces a risk…just that if you need to you already have a risk.